# How to create multiple tags in Fluentd from nested JSON keys

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, devops, fluentd

#### Update

What I was looking for was to format the output that was matched, not alter it with `rewrite_tag_filter`.

This worked as expected where the json keys were then parsed as openable fields within ElasticSearch instead of one massive string of the JSON object:

```
<source>
   @type dummy
   dummy client_ip: {"transaction":{"client_ip":"iphere","time_stamp":"Sun Jul 16 12:16:19 2023","server_id":"12345","client_port":12345,"host_ip":"iphere","host_port":443,"unique_id":"12345","request":{ "test": "true" },"response":{ "test": "true" },"producer":{ "test": "true" },"messages":["Test text"]}}
   tag mytag
   <parse>
      @type json
   </parse>
</source>

<match mytag>
   @type stdout
   <format>
      @type json
   </format>
</match>
```

#### Original Question

I'm trying to parse JSON logs into their own tags from a file which have the format

```
{"transaction":{"client_ip":"iphere","time_stamp":"Sun Jul 16 12:16:19 2023","server_id":"12345","client_port":12345,"host_ip":"iphere","host_port":443,"unique_id":"12345","request":{ ... },"response":{ ... },"producer":{ ... },"messages":[]}}
```

The `...` sections contain an arbitrary amount of data.

What I want is the nested top level keys in `"transaction"` to be tags so that when I view them in ElasticSearch they are separate drop downs.

Right now I can parse the value of `"transaction"` and send it with a single tag, which shows up as a single long string containing all of the data.

This result looks like this:

```
mytag: {"transaction":{"client_ip":"iphere","time_stamp":"Sun Jul 16 12:16:19 2023","server_id":"12345","client_port":12345,"host_ip":"iphere","host_port":443,"unique_id":"12345","request":{ ... },"response":{ ... },"producer":{ ... },"messages":[]}}
```

How do I create separate tags for each of those keys so it looks like:

```
"client_ip":"iphere",
"time_stamp":"Sun Jul 16 12:16:19 2023"
"server_id":"12345"
"client_port":12345
"host_ip":"iphere"
"host_port":443
"unique_id":"12345"
"request":{ ... }
"response":{ ... }
"producer":{ ... }
"messages":[]
```

Trying to understand `rewrite_tag_filter` I've tried to parse these two fields below with:

```
<source>
   @type dummy
   dummy client_ip: {"transaction":{"client_ip":"iphere","time_stamp":"Sun Jul 16 12:16:19 2023","server_id":"12345","client_port":12345,"host_ip":"iphere","host_port":443,"unique_id":"12345","request":{ "test": "true" },"response":{ "test": "true" },"producer":{ "test": "true" },"messages":["Test text"]}}
   tag mytag
</source>

<match mytag>
   @type rewrite_tag_filter
   <rule>
      key $['transaction']['client_ip']
      pattern .*
      tag client_ip
   </rule>
   <rule>
      key $['transaction']['time_stamp']
      pattern .*
      tag time_stamp
   </rule>
</match>

<match mytag>
   @type stdout
</match>
```

All this does, though, is rename the `mytag` to `client_ip`:

```
client_ip: {"transaction":{"client_ip":"iphere","time_stamp":"Sun Jul 16 12:16:19 2023","server_id":"12345","client_port":12345,"host_ip":"iphere","host_port":443,"unique_id":"12345","request":{ ... },"response":{ ... },"producer":{ ... },"messages":[]}}
```

Is `rewrite_tag_filter` even the right way to go about this?